# X11, nvidia-xconfig ruins internal monitor

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, nvidia

On X11, I'm trying to get both my internal and external monitors working at the same time. `nvidia-xconfig` generates this `xorg.conf` file:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 470.94


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

The issue is that the only works on external monitors (granted, any external monitor). Now I'm trying to get the internal monitor working. When I restart `sddm`, `xrandr`, or any other program, fails to see any other monitors/output devices despite the HDMI cable still being attached. Note that it is not put as "connected" or "disconnected", `xrandr -q` only returns the functioning monitor. This command however, still finds all monitors:

```
[lunar@J-Laptop 06:00:31pm /etc/X11]$  ls /sys/class/drm/*/edid | xargs -i{} sh -c "echo {}; parse-edid < {}"
/sys/class/drm/card0-eDP-1/edid
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier ""
    ModelName ""
    VendorName "NCP"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 1 of 2018
    # EDID version 1.4
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 340 190
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "false"
    Horizsync 162-162
    VertRefresh 48-120
    # Maximum pixel clock is 340MHz
    Modeline    "Mode 0" +hsync -vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 1" +hsync -vsync 
EndSection
/sys/class/drm/card1-HDMI-A-1/edid
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
"   Identifier "ELEFT195
"   ModelName "ELEFT195
    VendorName "ELE"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 27 of 2018
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 410 230
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "false"
    Horizsync 30-80
    VertRefresh 50-75
    # Maximum pixel clock is 230MHz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 800x600, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1024x768, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1440x900, 60Hz

    #Extension block found. Parsing...
    Modeline    "Mode 14" -hsync -vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 0" +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 1" 25.200 640 656 752 800 480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 2" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 3" 74.250 1280 1390 1420 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 4" 74.250 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1082 1087 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
    Modeline    "Mode 5" 27.027 1440 1478 1602 1716 480 484 487 525 -hsync -vsync interlace
    Modeline    "Mode 6" 148.500 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 7" 27.000 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 8" 74.250 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 9" 74.250 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1082 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
    Modeline    "Mode 10" 27.000 1440 1464 1590 1728 576 578 581 625 -hsync -vsync interlace
    Modeline    "Mode 11" 148.500 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 12" 74.250 1920 2558 2602 2750 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 13" 74.250 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 15" -hsync -vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 16" +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 17" +hsync +vsync interlace
    Option "PreferredMode" "Mode 14"
EndSection
```

Now what was given to me is very similar syntax to the `xorg.conf`, if not the exact. How do I use this to get both internal and external monitors working? Without any `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, only my internal monitor functions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

man [xorg.conf(5)](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/xorg.conf.5.html):

> The config file may have multiple **`Screen`** sections. There must be at least one, for the "screen" being used. **A "screen" represents the binding of a graphics device (`Device` section) and a monitor (`Monitor` section). A `Screen` section is considered "active" if it is referenced by an active `ServerLayout` section** ...

So you could try the add a second monitor and screen section and add the second screen section to the `serverlayout` section.
Use the position information field to position your monitors.

```
Section "Monitor"
Identifier     "Monitor1"
Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "Screen1"
Device         "Device0"
Monitor        "Monitor1"
DefaultDepth    24
SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier     "Layout0"
Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf 'Screen0"
InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection
```

`RightOf`, `LeftOf`, `Above` and `Below` are the four keywords
you can use to position your second screen.